# Packing MySQL database to java se application

Tags: java, mysql, installation, wampserver, packaging

I would like to know how professional software/s use their MySQL database created with wamp server. It means I think there is no product using WAMP/XAMMP etc. to use their database when after they packed their software.

I want to use them for a Desktop application. (Windows).

And I won't install WAMP on my/user's computer. I want to pack the database to my software installer. (I would like to create a setup with "Advanced Installer").

Is there any way to pack MySQL into the java application? And how to connect packed MySQL database.

Comment: If all you need for you software is JAVA and MySQL then there would be no point in distributing WAMPServer with Apache/MariaDB/PHP/phpMyAdmin/Adminers etc etc all sitting there doing nothing but taking up disk space. So you are probbaly correct, not many people would distribute WAMPServer/XAMPP with a JAVA based software package

Comment: You can of course package just MySQL with your install, if that is what you need. Remember WAMPServer/XAMPP are there to make it easy for beginners to get started in an AMP environment without having to learn about all the config required to get these things to all work together. And they are ment to be developer environment not a replacement for a properly configured and security hardened web server configuration

Comment: So how to pack MySQL into my project. Please help me.

Comment: I didn't see any resource about this title (How to pack MySQL to Java).

Comment: So which product are you using to make an Install. Thats where I woudl start to look for help

Comment: I'm using "Advanced Installer" (Unlimited - Architect)

Comment: Cannot help with that

Comment: In which installer you can help me?  I will use it.

Comment: Is yours a desktop Java program, or a server-based (tomcat, jetty, etc) program? Please [edit] your question to explain your requirement a little more completely.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make your users install WAMP. Seriously. They will hate you forever if you do; it can disrupt other things that run on their machines.

Because the installation of MySQL is a complex operation, you should refer your users to the published MySQL installation package. I suppose you could put their installer inside your installer, but it's hundreds of megabytes in size. You do *not* want to try to replicate their installer's functionality ... these installers take many months to develop and test.

If I were you I'd recommend the compatible [MariaDB fork of the MySQL server](https://mariadb.org/). Their [installer](https://mariadb.org/download/) is much less complex than the [bloated Oracle-furnished MySQL installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). Smaller, too.

If your Java program is to run on a desktop / laptop computer and stand alone, you may want to consider using an embedded SQL database like [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/index.html)
instead of connecting to an external MySQL database. It's packaged as a Java library so it can go in your installer along with the rest of your software. It's far less complex for users than a separate database instance.

If your Java program stands alone and you do use MySQL, tell your users they need MySQL and refer them to the installation package. If they already have WAMP they won't need to install it.

If your Java program runs on a desktop but will share data between multiple users, you need to install MySql just once, on one machine.

If your Java program runs on a Tomcat / Jetty  application web server, you can do the same thing.